# How to extract all words of a camel cased string with a regular expression?

Tags: regex, ruby

Assume I have a string that consists of multiple words. These words aren't separated by spaces, but every word starts with a capital letter. This type of naming convention is usually called "camel case". Some examples:

- ApplicationRecord
- CamelCase
- FirstNumberAfterACharacter

Now I want to split these strings into single words, so `FirstNumberAfterACharacter` becomes `["First", "Number", "After", "A", "Character"]` for example.

Finding a regular expression that matches those strings is also quite easy: `^([A-Z][a-z]*)+$`.
But if I try to get all matches, this regular expression will only return the last match:

```
irb(main):003:0> /^([A-Z][a-z]*)+$/.match('FirstNumberAfterACharacter').captures
=> ["Character"]

irb(main):004:0> 'FirstNumberAfterACharacter'.scan(/^([A-Z][a-z]*)+$/)
=> [["Character"]]
```

So how do I get all matches, not just the last one?

Comment: Repeating the capturing group will capture only the last iteration. You could match all occurrences without the anchors `[A-Z][a-z]*` if you know the format of the string.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know the number of words.

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but is this what you want? https://regex101.com/r/0nZEev/1/

Comment: @Thefourthbird is right, and you don't have to know the number of words; `scan` takes care of that. `p 'FirstNumberAfterACharacter'.scan(/[A-Z][a-z]*/) # =>["First", "Number", "After", "A", "Character"]`

Comment: @steenslag: Aaah. Thank you. That’s what I was looking for.

Comment: @steenslag Could you please write a "proper" answer with a short explanation?

Comment: @Thefourthbird came up with the solution to your question, I just demonstrated it briefly. I'm by no means a Regexp expert.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your regexp to:

start with a group `(...)` that consists of single capital letter: `[A-Z]{1}`, follows by zero or more capital letters `[^A-Z]*`.

```rb
'FirstNumberAfterACharacter'.scan(/([A-Z][^A-Z]*)/).flatten(1)
```

Comment: You can omit `{1}` after `[A-Z]`. Without a quantifier `{1}` is always the default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex that extract any kind of Unicode uppercase letter followed by any non-uppercase letters:

```rb
'FirstNumberAfterACharacter'.scan(/\p{Lu}\P{Lu}*/)
# => ["First", "Number", "After", "A", "Character"]
```

See the [Ruby online demo](https://ideone.com/PzuXFp).

*Details*:

- `\p{Lu}` - any Unicode letter
- `\P{Lu}*` - zero or more (`*`) letters other than Unicode letters.